# Creating a loop that goes through multiple rasters in a file and carries out QC

Tags: r, loops, geospatial, terra

I have created code which downloads individual hdf files from a folder, converts them into a raster and then using a QC raster, removes pixels in the NDVI and EVI layers.

However, I have around 4 individual files all in the same folder that span a time period of 1 month. I may download  files that span a year which would be considerably more files.

My question is, is it possible to create a loop which goes through all of the individual files, removes unnecessary layers of each one and finally carries out QC? Then, I can create a stack of all of the files in that folder.

My code for the individual file is as follows:

```
t <- rast("MYD13Q1.A2020313.h16v07.061.2020353215522.hdf")
names(t) #Check levels
ndvi_1 <- t[[1]] #Create raster with just ndvi
evi_1 <- t[[2]] #Create raster with just evi
qc_1 <- t[[12]] #Create raster with just qc
date_1 <- t[[11]] #Create raster with just date

plot(qc_1) #Check qc raster
qc_1[qc_1 > 1] <- NA #Remove pixels with a score of more than 1 as these are classed as bad pixels
ndvi_1_qc <- mask(ndvi_1, qc_1) #Remove pixels from ndvi by masking with qc raster
evi_1_qc <- mask(ndvi_1, qc_1) #Remove pixels from evi by masking with qc raster
plot(ndvi_1_qc)
stack1 <- (ndvi_1_qc, evi_1_qc, date_1) #Create raster stack
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have just hdf file in your folder.

```
library(terra)
applyQC <- function(path){
  
  t <- terra::rast(path)
  ndvi_1 <- t[[1]] #Create raster with just ndvi
  evi_1 <- t[[2]] #Create raster with just evi
  qc_1 <- t[[12]] #Create raster with just qc
  date_1 <- t[[11]] #Create raster with just date
  
  plot(qc_1) #Check qc raster
  qc_1[qc_1 > 1] <- NA #Remove pixels with a score of more than 1 as these are classed as bad pixels
  ndvi_1_qc <- terra::mask(ndvi_1, qc_1) #Remove pixels from ndvi by masking with qc raster
  evi_1_qc <- terra::mask(ndvi_1, qc_1) #Remove pixels from evi by masking with qc raster
  stack1 <- c(ndvi_1_qc, evi_1_qc, date_1) 
  return(stack1)
}

my_files <- list.files(path = "path/to/files",full.names = T)
stack_list <- lapply(my_files, applyQC)
stacks <- do.call(c,stack_list)
```

The idea is to wrap your code into a function and then `lapply` over the file path inside your folder. I suppose all .hdf files are identical in structure, layer names, CRS, resolution, etc.